# Change text color in jQuery append method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
socket.on('usernames', function(data, colour) {
  $('#usersInRoom').append($(data).css('color', colour) + "<br/>");
});
```

This code outputs:

```
[object Object]
```

Applying the css method ahead of time does not work. How can I accomplish the task of changing the colour of the string data?

Comment: Adding `"<br/>"` to a `$()` will turn the latter into a String, namely `[object Object]`. You need to append the jQuery object, then call append again to add a `$("<br/>")`.

Comment: The "<br>" was not the problem. I found an answer elsewhere and will post below for anyone's future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
socket.on('usernames', function(data, colour) {
    $('#usersInRoom')
        .append($('<span>').css('color', colour).text(data))
        .append($('<br>'))
    ;
});
```

you can't concat string with jQuery object